# Why do I get "does not reference a node" with XML document with namespaces using Ansbile XML module?

Tags: xml, xpath, ansible

Given the following XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Restricted URLs</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

I can for example use Ansible `xml` module to get the text **Restricted URLs**

```
- xml:
    path: "simple.xml"
    xpath: /web-app/security-constraint/web-resource-collection/web-resource-name
    content: text
  register: xmlresp

- debug:
    var: xmlresp
```

When I add a namespace to the xml for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee">
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Restricted URLs</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

and change Ansible YAML code to

```
- xml:
    path: xml-with-namespace.xml"
    xpath: /x:web-app/security-constraint/web-resource-collection/web-resource-name
    content: text
    namespaces:
      x: "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  register: xmlresp

- debug:
    var: xmlresp
```

This produces error message

> TASK [centos : xml]
> ******************************************************** fatal: [centos]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Xpath
> /x:web-app/security-constraint/web-resource-collection/web-resource-name
> does not reference a node!"}

Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

The `xpath` expression is incorrect. Each element should be prefixed with the namespace `/x:web-app/x:security-constraint/x:web-resource-collection/x:web-resource-name`

```
- xml:
    path: xml-with-namespace.xml"
    xpath: /x:web-app/x:security-constraint/x:web-resource-collection/x:web-resource-name
    content: text
    namespaces:
      x: "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  register: xmlresp

- debug:
    var: xmlresp
```

See [community.general.xml – Manage bits and pieces of XML files or strings — Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/xml_module.html?highlight=xml)